# Pull posts randomly instead of by date in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using a theme that uses some code to interact with the database to pull posts. I am new when it comes to this but have reviewed the WordPress documentation on these types of queries and could not figure out how to make this random instead of by date. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
return "{$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value + 0 {$order}, {$wpdb->posts}.post_date DESC";
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit Full Code:

```
    public function posts_orderby()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $order = "DESC";

    if (isset($_REQUEST['sortby']) && $_REQUEST['sortby'] == 'price') {
        $order = "ASC";
    }

    // return "{$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value DESC";
    return "{$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value + 0 {$order}, {$wpdb->posts}.post_date DESC";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this - `return "{$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value + 0 {$order}, {$wpdb->posts}.post_date ORDER BY RAND()";`

Comment: That was my first try, unfortunately it did not do the trick.It seems you can only used ASC & DESC in that spot.

Comment: Updated main post.

Comment: Maybe try: return "{$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value + 0 {$order}, ORDER BY RAND({$wpdb->posts}.post_date)";

Comment: Unfortunately it still returns nothing :(